# Ubuntu performance on a VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a VirtualBox on Windows 7 host. The problem is that the UI lags a lot. I already installed Guest Additions and etc and enabled 3D acceleration, though it made things faster it's still not running smooth. I already have Ubuntu installed on this machine as dual-boot so I have an example for how smooth the system should run.

Is there some configuration that should run Ubuntu smoothly?

Here are some specs:

Host machine:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- 4GB RAM
- Nvidia 9600GT
- QuadCore Q8300 2.50GHz

Guest machine:

- Ubuntu 13.04 64bit
- 1GB RAM
- 2 Processor cores
- 8 GB Space
- 3D accelartion enabled

Comment: Please define "running smoothly" Do you have graphical problems, glitches, short term lock-ups, heavy disk access?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207813/why-does-an-ubuntu-12-10-guest-in-virtualbox-run-very-very-slowly), it appears that from Ubuntu 12.10 on, Unity 2D is no longer available. It includes a detailed guide on enabling 3D acceleration that should solve your problem.